# Is there any way I can order Rendering tabs?

Tags: sxa, presentation, components

Is there any way I can order Rendering tabs to appear when adding a new component to the page? I tried this from available rendering but it didn't work out

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default ordering of tabs is set to alphabetical order of folders which contain components (their Display Names).

With SXA you can use the checkbox on `Presentation/Available Renderings` item called `Group renderings in sections according to Available Renderings items in the site`.

[image]